# Make a sum in a column in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have got a dataframe with many columns and different types for each column  (text, date, integer ...) .

I want to sum one of this column and print the result.

I try different example with colsums and others but nothing ...

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page. In particular you need to present a specific problem including input data in reproducible form, expected output and the R code of your best attempt.

Comment: `sum(data$column)` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can probably make use of the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
your_data_frame %>%
as_tibble() %>%
summarise(across(c("var01", "var02"), sum))
```